# UILabel to automatic line break when line is too long

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

My UILabel can do a line break according to the current \n . But if the line itself is too long, it won't be able to automatically do a line break. Can I do more configurations to my UILabel to achieve that?

And I've already used:

```
aLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
aLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[aLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Wide" size:24]];
aLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;

CGRect labelFrame = aLabel.bounds;

labelFrame.size = [words sizeWithFont:aLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, 100000) lineBreakMode:aLabel.lineBreakMode];

aLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, aLabel.frame.size.width-10, labelFrame.size.height);
```

words is a NSString

Comment: Post the full code you use to create/customize `aLabel`

Comment: The last line shouldn't be like this? `aLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, aLabel.frame.size.width-10, labelFrame.size.height);
`

Comment: Apologies. Made a mistake when pasting the codes here.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code!

Comment: Yep! But the link breaks are only done for the actual line breaks in the word (\n). But if 1 line is too long, the label wont be able to automatically insert a line break!

Comment: This happens only if the **label's width is too large**, or, **numberOfLines is 0**

Comment: So should I reduce the the LABEL_WIDTH in constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, 100000) ? I tried that but it's still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Number of line as you want to set.

```
aLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

Comment: This is not necessary. Setting `numberOfLines` to `0` will make the *UILabel* to adopt itself to show any number of lines.

Comment: @EmptyStack: It's not good to edit the answer by removing just 4 spaces. Guessing the reason...!!!

Comment: You have all rights to rollback to your previous edit if you don't like my edit (and don't like your answer to be formatted properly)!

Answer (score -1):

if you are having text in a paragraph and want to place it in a lable with differ lines no need to use UILineBreakModeWordWrap.. simply write one line code as in how many lines you want to place the text as

```
labobj.numberOfLines = 90;
```

Comment: Under this situation, won't numberOfLines = 0 be good enough?